# await not waiting for child function to execute first in react

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```
async fetchJobs() {
        this.setState({ isFetching: true }, async () => {
            try{
                debugger;
                console.log("fetching Jobs");
                var body = {
                    page: this.state.page,
                    sortBy: this.state.sortBy,
                    comparator: this.state.comparator,
                    batch: this.state.batch,
                    role: this.state.role,
                    companies: this.state.selectedCompanies
                }
                var job = await axios({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/page_job?page=${this.state.page}`,
                    params: body
                });
                const page_jobs = job.data.page;
                const jc = job.data.count;
        
                const jobcount = parseInt(jc);
        
                this.setState({
                    jobs: page_jobs,
                    jobcount: jobcount
                }, () => {
                    this.getPagination();
                    if (this.refJobs.current)
                        this.refJobs.current.scrollTop = 0;
                });
                debugger;
                console.log("fetched jobs");
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log("err1");
                throw error;
            }
            finally{
                this.setState({ isFetching: false });
            }
        });    
    }
```

```
filterHandler = async (body) => {
        this.setState({
            page: 1,
            sortBy: body.sortBy,
            comparator: body.comparator,
            batch: body.batch,
            role: body.role,
            selectedCompanies: body.selectedCompanies
        }, async () => {
            tr{
               await this.fetchJobs();
               console.log("not catching error");
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log("err2");
                throw error;
            }
        })
    }
```

When filterHandler function is called through await it is giving output as:
fetching jobs
not catching error
fetched jobs,
instead of:
fetching jobs
fetched jobs
not catching error
I am not able to understand how to use async/await to get the desired output. As async/await should
have stopped the parent function, executed the child and then returned to the parent function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `await fetchJobs`, you are not awaiting the `fetch` Promise.

Try this:

```js
async fetchJobs() {
  this.setState({ isFetching: true });
  try {
    // ...
  }
  catch(error) {
    // ...
  }
  finally {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Another option is to explicitly generate and resolve a Promise:

```js
fetchJobs = () => new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  this.setState({ isFetching: true }, async () => {
    try {
      // ...
      debugger;
      console.log("fetched jobs");
      resolve(jobcount); // For example...
    }
    catch(error) {
      // ...
      reject(error);
    }
    finally {
      // Not sure if this is going to be executed, probably not
      this.setState({ isFetching: false });
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Will it not create a problem if I remove the callback from setState as it can cause try block to be executed before seState is completed?

Comment: I don't think so. The first `setState` will be executed before the rest, and it's results will be available in the same render in which the `fetch` is fired.

Comment: I read that setStates are asynchronous in nature and if we need statements to be executed after that we need to put them in a callback. Also I am still unclear why putting try/catch block outside the callback is making it work. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: If this is an enforcement from your employer, then use the _explicit `Promise`_ version. If not, then the first one should go just fine.

Comment: can you also please explain why putting try/catch block outside the callback is making it work?

Comment: Sorry, what callback?

Comment: The callback which I have put in setState, when we are putting the try/catch block outside of it as you have shown it is working.

Comment: Ahh, now I undertand the question :) In your question you where awaiting `fetchJobs`, but this, in turn, was NOT -correctñy- awaiting the `axios`. Well, it was awaiting it, but it was called inside the `setState` callback, which was NOT awaited from `fetchJobs` (and I think it cannot be awaited), so `fetchJobs` exited just after `setState` (in some cases, even before the `axios` request is created). Does this answers your question?